# Is it mandatory to migrate the SCR annotations to OSGi R6 annotations in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

We are migrating from AEM 6.1 to 6.3. I have deployed my 6.1 code with new uber jar using maven. I got a success message while deploying and installed the package in AEM 6.3.

Since SCR annotations are deprecated in 6.3, Is it mandatory to migrate them to OSGI R6 annotations? I am not getting any error in deploying the code or error.log file..

Answer (score 1):

> Since SCR annotations are deprecated in 6.3, Is it mandatory to migrate them to OSGI R6 annotations?

I haven't seen anything in the release notes about that; regardless, when something is "deprecated" means you can still use it but support will be removed in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not mandatory, scr annotations are only used for generating scr descriptors during build process. Scr descriptors are XML files in osgi-conf folder that tells Felix what all OSGi components/services are there in your bundle.

if you can find other ways to generate descriptors you don't need the annotations at all.

If you keep using older versions of annotations you open yourself to the following problems-

- If they introduce some new annotations, your code will not be able to generate them and will break.
- Since annotations processing happens on compiled code. It may fail with newer versions of jdk, since newer bytecode may not be readable by old version of annotation processor.